# OSX - How can I copy a local users settings/preferences to a new mobile user

Tags: macos, bash, sh, osx-mavericks

We are working on migrating all our local users to mobile accounts that are bound to LDAP.
I am working on a script that prompts a user to enter their email and it creates a new mobile user and then moves all their files and also their preferences.

Perfect world, user logs out of local account and into the new account and it looks just like it did before the move (including desktop wallpaper,dock settings, etc..).

I've figured out how to create the mobile account from user prompt.

I think I have the files figured out using mv due to the amount of files/folders are too big to copy.

What I am having issues is with the settings/preferences.

I've figured that the keychain isn't going to work easily so I'm ok with that not being a part of it.

I've tried rsync'ing the Library/Preferences but it's not working....
Anyone had any experience with this?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/ might be a better audience for this question.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, was planning on adding this there later...  Moving info between profiles doesn't require a server so I was hoping someone with experience might see it here.